# how to have body background image only on landing page

Tags: css, css-selectors, background-image

I've created a second page of my website and my first page is simply a landing page with the background image. However, when i go onto the second page I created, the background image i use on my landing page is also shown on that page which I do not want there.

Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484417894907-623942c8ee29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
font-family: 'Lato';
color: white;
}
```

Note:
I've also tried `background-repeat: no-repeat;` but it did not work.

Comment: Ive tried that and it still shows the bg image on the second page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a class to your landing page's `body` element and change your CSS rule and selector/s to only select `body` with that particular class.

HTML for the landing page would be

```
<body class="mylandingpage">
   ....
```

For other pages: `<body>` *without* a class (or with another class)

And the CSS:

```
body {
 background: none;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 color: white;
}

body.mylandingpage {
 background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484417894907-623942c8ee29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
}
```

(`color` might also be specific to the landing page, I don't know...)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a separate div class for your background as the body tag will always get called for all of your pages. Use some thing like this, try and only assign things to the body that you will want across all pages.

```
<div class="background">

....
```

Then add your CSS to this class

```
//CSS file 
.background {
background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484417894907-623942c8ee29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.